# Check what numbers in a list are divisible by certain numbers?

Tags: python, math, for-loop, list-comprehension

Write a function that receives a list of numbers
and a list of terms and returns only the elements that are divisible
by all of those terms. You must use two nested list comprehensions to solve it.

divisible_numbers([12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1], [2, 3])  # returns  [12, 6]

def divisible_numbers(a_list, a_list_of_terms):

I have a vague pseudo code so far, that consists of check list, check if divisible if it is append to a new list,  check new list check if divisible by next term and repeat until, you have gone through all terms, I don't want anyone to do this for me but maybe a hint in the correct direction?

Comment: Here is a good place to start https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The inner expression should check if for a particular number, that number is evenly divisible by all of the terms in the second list

```
all(i%j==0 for j in a_list_of_terms)
```

Then an outer list comprehension to iterate through the items of the first list

```
[i for i in a_list if all(i%j==0 for j in a_list_of_terms)]
```

All together

```
def divisible_numbers(a_list, a_list_of_terms):
    return [i for i in a_list if all(i%j==0 for j in a_list_of_terms)]
```

Testing

```
>>> divisible_numbers([12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1], [2, 3])
[12, 6]
```

Comment: nice use of all function here.

Comment: If the lists are large you might want to consider optimizing your inputs first by checking the terms do not have common factors. That way you are not doing needless checks. For example, there's no point in processing 6 as a term in [2,3,6] when anything divisible by 6 will be divisible by 2 and 3.

Comment: Nice use of "all". If you put any in place, it's an interesting case for comparing all and any

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get input from the user using this type of way.

```
enter code hereprint("numbers which are divisible by 5")
user_input=eval(input("enter the value in list type [1,2,3]: "))**
print(type(user_input)) if type(user_input)==list: for i in
user_input: if(i%5==0): print(i,end=",") else:
    print("none")
```

## OUTPUT:

```
numbers that are divisible by 5 enter the value in list type [1,2,3]:
   [15,10,20,45,69] <class 'list'> 15,10,20,45,
```